# Zend - Autoloader issue

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend (and here) & after getting it installed, I'm running into this

> error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Zend' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\public\invoice.php on line 4**

```
<?php
define("ZF_PATH", realpath("C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\"));
set_include_path(get_include_path('C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library') . PATH_SEPARATOR . ZF_PATH);
require_once "Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php";
```

This is the initial tutorial that I was following: http://www.sitepoint.com/generating-invoices-with-zend_pdf/

I'm basically just looking for a way to generate a report or page off of a form submitted to a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

The `\` is an [escape character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and when in front of a `"` is escapes that quote so PHP thinks it is part of that string and continues to look for the closing quote. You can see in the syntax highlighting that PHP considers everything up to `Zend` to be part of the same string.

To fix this you can either use double slashes:

```
define("ZF_PATH", realpath("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\zend\\"));
```

or use `/` instead of `\`

```
define("ZF_PATH", realpath("C:/xampp/htdocs/zend/"));
```

Comment: Duh!  Thankyou.  
So now I am receiving the error: *Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader_Autoloader' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\public\invoice.php on line 6*    
    
`$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();`